Distribution of the correlation coefficient based on quadratic forms
Let $x,y$ be two independent random correlated vectors following the same multivariate (real or complex) centred normal distribution, and let $A$ be a non-negative linear operator.
We can read here, here and there that the quadratic form $x^\ast Ax$ (with conjugate transposition) is distributed as a weighted sum of Chi-squared. My question is the following:
What is the distribution of $\displaystyle \frac{|y^\ast Ax|^2}{x^\ast Ax \cdot y^\ast Ay}$?
I don't expect a nice closed form, but perhaps some insights about asymptotic approximation beyond the beta law, which is a correct approximation for $(\text{Tr}A)^2\gg Tr(AA^\ast)$.
